# Problems with SignalR Core and SQL Notification

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I am developing a SignalR .Net 5 MVC application that uses SignalR to notify clients of inbound calls logged to a database.  I am using the javascript sdk to perfrom client notifications.  I ahve also confirmed the SQL Server Service Broker is enabled and working.  Here is my controller code:

```
    public class CallNotificationHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public async Task SendCallNotifications()
    {
        
        try
        {
            string connectionString = myConnString;
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [TimeEntered], [CallFrom], [CallTo] FROM [dbo].[tbl_Log_InboundTwilioCalls]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            
            dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dependency.AddCommandDependency(command);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Reached", "New SignalR5 SendCallNotifications at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendEmail sendErrEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Error", ex.ToString(), "");
        }

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveNotification", "Changed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("Dependency Change", e.Type.ToString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "");
        CallNotificationHub nHub = new CallNotificationHub();
        nHub.SendCallNotifications();

    }
}
```

The javascript notification script:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/CallNotificationHub").build();

connection.on("RecieveNotification", (result) => {


console.log(result);
alert("Result=" + result);
alert("CallNotification2 Changed");
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    connection.invoke("SendCallNotifications").catch(err => console.error(err));
}).catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

On the initial page load, the notification works as expected and writes a response to the console.       However, when the database updates, the email notifications fire, however, the clients do not update.  I stuck as to where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Pls check the error message in output.

Comment: I have seen you have created a same issue in 5/25/2021, and  why you create the sample post. The problem persists or the problem is reproduced after modifying something. Please pay attention to whether the project has been updated and deployed recently.

Comment: There is no error message in output that I can see.  I was never able to get ths project to work with .Net Core.  Instead, I reverted back to .Net 4.5.

Comment: Pls enable tracing feature and [use debugdiag tool to collect the logs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-has-stopped-responding-in-iis-995db9a3-a3be-6d20-cf2f-c48101a64444). You need host your app in IIS first, and try to reproduce the issue, you can get the log.

Comment: I'll try that, but I really don't think it is an IIS issue.  Within the same project, I have a working SignalR chat application.

Comment: I know this is not an IIS problem, but I want to grab more useful application logs this way.

Comment: I changed the dependency OnChage to:`        private async void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("Dependency Change", e.Type.ToString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "");
            CallNotificationHub nHub = new CallNotificationHub();

            await nHub.SendCallNotifications();            

        }  Now receiving error in the console Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ()

Comment: A process serving application pool 'SignalR5' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '13384'. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: Can you show the error pic for us ?  And pls hide sensitive info.

Comment: Does anyone have a working example of .Net Core SignalR with Sqll Notification?  Doesn't seem to be any out there.  Is this simply not supported anymore?

Comment: Hi Greybeard, hope you are doing well. I want to know the email content at the second time, when you call this method. Can you show us pls.

Comment: If you refer to my sample code, the email content is simply the date and time of the database update.  I'm really not even trying to return anything from the database to the browser at this point because I am simply trying to get any type of borwser update working consistently.  By chance, have you tried my sample code to see if you get the same problem?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like below. It works for me.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using signalr.Interface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace signalr.Hubs
{
    public class CallNotificationHub : Hub, ICallNotificationHub
    {
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public async Task SendCallNotifications()
        {

            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=.************ue; Connection Timeout=30;";
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM [dbo].[Restaurant]";
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                counter = 0; //Whenewer the web method is called, set te counter to 0
                //dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dependency.AddCommandDependency(command);

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                Console.WriteLine("SendCallNotifications Reached"+ "New SignalR5 SendCallNotifications at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                //SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Reached", "New SignalR5 SendCallNotifications at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SendCallNotifications Error " + DateTime.Now.ToString()+ ex.ToString());
                //SendEmail sendErrEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Error", ex.ToString(), "");
            }

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveNotification", "Changed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("RecieveNotification " + "Changed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        }
        public int counter = 0;
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
       

            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change && e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update && counter == 0)
            {
                //Call SignalR  
                Console.WriteLine("Dependency Change " + e.Type.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                //SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("Dependency Change", e.Type.ToString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "");
                CallNotificationHub nHub = new CallNotificationHub();
                nHub.SendCallNotifications();
                counter++; //The update is done once
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 0; //if the update is needed in the same iteration, please don't update and set the counter to 0
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which leads me back to my original post.  I think my problem is in the javascript update code, but am not sure.  Are you receiving actual updates to the browser, or simply getting notifications from the controller.

Comment: @Greybeard Just try it.

Comment: I did.  Tried it on laptop using VS 2019, SQL Server 2012, and IIS Express.  Client only updates on first page load, but controller sends notifications  Then moved to a production machine, Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012.  Same result as the testing machine.  Alerts fire 0n first page load.  After first pabe load, only email notifications.

Comment: Does anyone have a truly working SignalR Core with SQL backplane?  I'm obviosuly close to having this working, but don't find any examples.  Is this no longer being supported?

Comment: @Greybeard can you schedule a time,and I can chat with you.

Comment: @Greybeard I will have time 1.5h later.

Comment: What timezone are you in?  Give me a few time options

Comment: Lets try to catch up tomorrow.  Please send me an email.  Hot sure how you wanted to do this.

Comment: @Greybeard Sorry I can’t give you email account, and this month I will reply you during 1pm-10pm utc+8, you can chat with me by leaving a message in this post.